# Char array declaring problems

Tags: c, arrays, char

Why can I do

```
char identifier[4] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
```

and not

```
char identifier[4];
&identifier = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}; // syntax error : '{'
```

?

And why can I do

```
char identifier[4] = "ABCD"; // ABCD\0, aren't that 5 characters??
```

and not

```
char identifier[4];
&identifier = "ABCD"; // 'char (*)[4]' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [5]'
```

?

Is this a joke??

Comment: You can always do this if you need to separate the declaration from the assignment: `char identifier[4]; sprintf(identifier, "ABCD");`. Just make sure that the assigned string fits in the allocated array or use the secure version, [`sprintf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok thanks! This works but why would I need a function for something simple like this...

Comment: @Jaime: Do you not think sprintf() is perhaps a sledgehammer to crack a nut in this case? memcpy() will suffice *and* solves the issue that you propose sprintf_s() for.

Comment: @Midas:  Because an array is not a data-type in C, it is a contiguous sequence of objects of the same type. Arrays do not behave like objects.

Comment: @Midas: Clifford is correct. You do not need to use the string format modifiers in `sprintf`. You should use `char identifier[4]; memcpy(identifier, "ABCD", 4)`.

Comment: That will require one more header file... Can't I just use stdio.h only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points:

- Initialisation is not *assignment*
- Arrays are not first-class types so cannot be assigned.  You have to assign the elements individually (or use a function such as strcpy() or memcpy().
- The address of an array is provided by the array name on its own.

In your last example, the following is a valid solution:

```
char identifier[4];
memcpy(identifier, "ABCD", sizeof(identifier) ) ;
```

You cannot use strcpy() here, because that would require an array of 5 characters to allow for the nul terminator.  The error message about levels of indirection is not a "joke", it is *your* error; note in the above code `identifier` does not have a `&` operator, since that would make it a `char**` where a `char*` is required.

Comment: +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 but I would elaborate a little more on what "Initialization is not assignment" means to a newbie.

Comment: @Clifford, `the address of an array is provided by the array name on its own` is misleading and teaching the wrong thing. I'd go for something like `using the array name by its own evaluates to the address of the first element`.

Comment: @Jens:  Maybe, I'll let it stand as I think it is clear enough. I have distinctly not said that the array name *is* a pointer.  Your comment may serve as clarification to anyone who thinks it necessary.  I was trying to be succinct.

Comment: Using the `&` operator on `identifier` doesn't make it a `char **`, it makes it a `char (*)[4]` (as the compiler's error message attests).  These are quite different types.

Comment: @caf: I know.  However what memcpy() receives is a `char*`.  That is what I meant by "where a `char*` is required"; memcpy() *requires* a 'char*'.  While I agree with you, in this case the distinction is irrelevant, so I never mentioned it - again for succinctness.

Comment: @Clifford: `memcpy()` actually requires a `void *`, and in this case both `&identifier` and `identifier` are fine (since one is the address of the array itself, and one is the address of the array's first element; when converted to `void *` these are necessarily identical).

Comment: @caf: Good point.  However it is an odd and unnecessary habit that should probably not be encouraged.  If for example you wrote `char* alias = identifier ;` alias and &alias are *not* the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can only initialize the array when you declare it.

As for `char identifier[4] = "ABCD"`, this is indeed possible but the syntax is used to deliberately omit the trailing NUL character. Do `char identifier[] = "ABCD"` to let the compiler count the characters and add the NUL (`'\0'`) for you.

Comment: Plus in the second code, the `&identifier` is a pointer to array.

Comment: Yeah, I just assumed that the `&` syntax was something the OP tried to invent for doing something that's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

What Arkku said, but also, you cannot assign to the address of something, i.e. `&x = ...` is never legal.